# how to use mod_rewrite with godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using godaddy linux shared hosting and i am having some problem with mod_rewrite.
I am not much familier with mod_rewrite
my code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule readfile.php(.*)$ seceretfile.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

this code works file on my localhost but online it doesn't work when i go to readfile.php it shows file not found AND also when i type a file without .php extension it shows an error?

Comment: I bet it's because of **seceret** file.php

Comment: @webarto which seceret file ??

Comment: @webarto this is only a file name......does it matter what it is...??

Comment: @Lokesh it doesn't matter, you *.htaccess* doesn't make much sense, also, it doesn't matter if it's GoDaddy, also, ask the forking hosting support.

Comment: they only told me that rewrite_module in on......and (seceretfile.php) is not the realname of the file that i have on my server it's just a fake name....>??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i found a solution

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule readfile.php(.*)$ lebetafile.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

now this code works for me..But a new problem happens that the orignal 404 error file is not working and i don't know about the security risks of this But this is working fine with godaddy